# TypeError -- list indices must be integers or slices, not str

Tags: python, json, list

I am working on automating the processes of connecting to the switch and upgrading the image. Code I have so far is:

```
def check_redundancy(task):
get_redundancy = task.run(task = netmiko_send_command, command_string = 'show redundancy summary', use_ttp = True, ttp_template = ' ')
task.host['redundancy'] = get_redundancy.result
results = 'SHOW REDUNDANCY INFO'
print(task.host['redundancy'])
return Result(host = task.host, result = results)

def verify_redundancy(task):
    peer_state = 'ACTIVE'
    for i in task.host['redundancy']:
        if i['peer_state'] == peer_state:
            results = str(f"Redundancy check, looking for {i['peer_state']} -- found")
            check = 'Y'
            task.host['check'] = 'Y'
        else:
            results = str(f"Redundancy check, looking for {i['peer_state']} -- did not find it")
            check = 'N'
            task.host['check'] = 'N'
        return Result(host=task.host, result=f"{(Style.BRIGHT)} {(Fore.WHITE)}{(Back.GREEN)} {results}",check=check)
    return Result(host=task.host, result=f"{(Style.BRIGHT)} {(Fore.WHITE)}{(Back.YELLOW)} {results}",check=check)
```

task.host['redundancy'] output looks like this:

```
[ [ { 'redundancy': { 'link_encryption': 'ENABLED',
                      'local_state': 'STANDBY HOT',
                      'mobility_mac': 'xxx',
                      'peer_state': 'ACTIVE',
                      'redundancy_mode': 'SSO ENABLED',
                      'redundancy_port': 'UP',
                      'redundancy_state': 'SSO',
                      'unit': 'Primary',
                      'unit_id': 'xxx',
                      'verage_management_gateway_reachability_latency': '933 '
                                                                        'Micro '
                                                                        'Seconds',
                      'verage_redundancy_peer_reachability_latency': '293 '
                                                                     'Micro '
                                                                     'Seconds'}}]]
```

After I run this, I get error:

```
if i['peer_state'] == peer_state:
TypeError: list indices must be integers or slices, not str
```

Any ideas how to fix this so I can look at the output and see compare the peer_state?
Thank you in advance

Comment: Option 1: Make sure `i` is a dictionary, not a list. Option 2: don't use a string as an index for the list `i`.

Comment: Hi Michal, the indentation in the first definition is wrong.

Comment: @GianlucaMicchi so should I fix my parser?

Comment: It's probably fixed already in your local copy, otherwise it wouldn't run. I'm referring to the fact that the body of the function `check_redundancy(task)` is aligned to the left of the document instead of being 4 white spaces to the right. https://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0008/#indentation

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your JSON object contains 2 lists within each other.

If you do:

`for i in task.host['redundancy']`

you only tap into the first. Depending on how your object scales you should probably add another loop or remove unnecessary lists.